# What are senescent cells doing in our bodies?

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, senescence

I'm reading a paper that mentioned the elimination of senescent cells delays aging. I'd like to receive more information about it.

The Baker study published in Nature demonstrates that targeted elimination of senescent cells in mice results in remarkable protection from several age-related pathologies, cancer, and makes cancer cells resistant to chemotherapy. I know that senescent cells drive aging, and induce cancer. Can we grow them in cell culture as a kind of stem cells ? How might they contribute to the aging process ?

Comment: Welcome to Biology. Could you provide a source for this claim? Also, have you done any research on this topic, such as performing a simple Google search for "senescent cells", reading the Wikipedia page, or clicking on the `[senescence]` tag in your question and reading some of the linked questions? If not, please do so, then [edit] your question to include what you know so far, and what **specifically** you still have questions about. Otherwise, this post may be closed as "homework."

Comment: @MattDMo Did you actually review this one? I'm asking because it isn't in queue, and I thought it would be.

Comment: @L.B. nope, I just saw it appear on the main page

Comment: Hi,my question is the senescent cells is kind of aging cells? What are the similarities and differences between them?

Comment: Voted to re-open. Although there are some misconceptions here this question is well within the realms of an overview answer of our current knowledge, in my opinion.

Comment: Edited the question, prepared a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @MattDMo I know that was a strange question on my part... I was just confused! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. I would like to further clarify my question by stating that cells reach senescent state after prolonged cell stress caused by DNA damage.The study published in Aging Cell indicates that senescent cells are seen with increased frequency in premature aging skin and are thought to cause age-related dermal thinning thus, accelerate aging of the skin. I'd like to know are both terms (cell aging and cell senescence) the same? Is a senescent cell an aged cell? If a young cell undergo a stress or damage can be induce senescence? Thank you .

Comment: @Microbiologist please include a direct link to the paper you are asking about (PubMed, DOI, etc.) so that we can answer your specific questions. *"The Baker study published in Nature"* is not very helpful...

Answer (score -2):

Senescent cells are cells that go into permanent cell cycle arrest. Although they may be metabolically active, they are not actively dividing. This may occur when cells in our bodies undergo damage from an extraneous or endogenous source. I understand that its role in cancer and aging is a great topic of study.

Comment: this is a rather incomplete answer, and could easily skew a newcomer's viewpoint. Many, if not most of the cells in the body are senescent, and will never divide again. However, they is programmed to do this, it is not as a result of damage.